# TensorFlow DeepOCR cannot feed value of shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr

I want OCR text from photo. read [this](https://nicholastsmith.wordpress.com/2017/10/14/deep-learning-ocr-using-tensorflow-and-python/) article
I saw the [github](https://github.com/nicholastoddsmith/pythonml) project. and I would love to work

But...
I deleted all the files in the **TFModel** folder. To be re-created.
When I run **DeepOCR.py**
Gives the following error.

> ValueError: cannot feed value of shape (512, 17, 704, 3) for Tensor 'TFIM:0', which has shape '(?, 18, 640, 3)'

Thank you for helping me

Comment: check the dimension of the tensor that you are feeding for `'TFIM:0'`.